# BGP routing multi-homes router

Tags: bgp, cisco-ios

right now this is our current BGP config. we have two class C's and two ISP's. we would like both networks to prefer the Verizon path 157.130.124.197 for inbound over ATT while we do maintenance on the ATT circuit and would like some advice on the best way of doing this. thank you

```
router bgp 1123
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 12.80.93.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 208.220.256.0
 neighbor 12.88.105.13 remote-as 7020
 neighbor 12.88.105.13 version 4
 neighbor 12.88.105.13 send-community
 neighbor 157.131.125.121 remote-as 704
 neighbor 157.131.125.121 version 4
 neighbor 157.131.125.121 send-community
 no auto-summary
```

Comment: Where are the Class C addresses?

Comment: I think that's AS702, not AS7020.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Shut down your BGP session with ATT and wait a few minutes for BGP to converge globally, that should do the trick.

Comment: Or mark your announcements to ATT "no-export", so they apply only to things within their AS.